# When scala.concurrent.Future's execution starts?

Tags: scala, future, execution, systemtime

Of course one could collect the system time at the first line of the Future's body. But:

Is it possible to know that time without having access to the future's code. (In my case the method returning the future is to be provided by the user of the 'framework'.)

```
def f: Future[Int] = ...

def magicTimePeak: Long = ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Future` itself doesn't really know this (nor was it designed to care). It's all up to the executor when the code will actually be executed. This depends on whether or not a thread is immediately available, and if not, when one becomes available.

---

You could wrap `Future`, to keep track of it, I suppose. It would involve creating an underlying `Future` with a closure that changes a mutable var within the wrapped class. Since you just want a `Long`, it would have to default to zero if the `Future` hasn't begun executing, though it would be trivial to change this to `Option[Date]` or something.

```
class WrappedFuture[A](thunk: => A)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {

    var started: Long = 0L

    val underlying = Future {
        started = System.nanoTime / 1000000 // milliseconds
        thunk
    }

}
```

To show that it works, create a fixed thread pool with one thread, then feed it a blocking task for say, 5 seconds. Then, create a `WrappedFuture`, and check it's `started` value later. Note the difference in the logged times.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent._
val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executorService)

scala> println("Before blocked: " + System.nanoTime / 1000000)
Before blocked: 13131636

scala> val blocker = Future(Thread.sleep(5000))
blocker: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7e5d9a50

scala> val f = new WrappedFuture(1)
f: WrappedFuture[Int] = WrappedFuture@4c4748bf

scala> f.started
res13: Long = 13136779 // note the difference in time of about 5000 ms from earlier
```

If you don't control the creation of the `Future`, however, there is nothing you can do to figure out when it started.